# DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_job_argument_value - ORA-27473: argument does not exist

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, job-scheduling, dbms-job

Hi I'm creating a JOB CONTROLLER to run a procedure.

**JOB CONTROLLER Procedure**'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "GCCPMAINT"."JOB_CONTROLLER" as
        programTotal number;    
BEGIN
        dbms_scheduler.create_program (
                   program_name           =>  'PGM_CLEANSE_BRNGB',
                   program_type           =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                   program_action         =>  'OPT_SALES',
                   number_of_arguments => 1,
                   enabled            =>  FALSE);


        dbms_scheduler.DEFINE_PROGRAM_ARGUMENT(
                program_name=>'PGM_CLEANSE_BRNGB',
                argument_name=>'card_no',
                argument_position=>1,
                argument_type=>'varchar2');

        dbms_scheduler.enable('PGM_CLEANSE_BRNGB');

        DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_job(job_name => 'JOB_Cleanse_BRNGB', force => true);
        dbms_scheduler.create_job('JOB_Cleanse_BRNGB',program_name=>'PGM_CLEANSE_BRNGB',auto_drop=> true,start_date=>SYSDATE,job_style=> 'LIGHTWEIGHT');

        dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(
                               job_name=>'JOB_Cleanse_BRNGB',
                               argument_name=>'card_no',---> error says here
                               argument_value=>'1234');

        dbms_scheduler.enable('JOB_Cleanse_BRNGB');
END;
```

here is my program action procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "OPT_SALES"(card_no VARCHAR2)
as
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('card-Number is'||card_no);
END;
```

When i try to run the job controller procedure it says error as

> 17:42:28  [@CALL - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 27473, SQL
>   State: 99999]  ORA-27473: argument CARD_NO does not exist ORA-06512:
>   at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 244 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER",
>   line 716 ORA-06512: at "GCCPMAINT.JOB_CONTROLLER", line 27 ORA-06512:
>   at line 1

I have the right argument then why it says **"argument CARD_NO does not exist"**

Can anybody help me please.

Comment: That is strange.  Worked for me.  What oracle version?

Comment: @OldProgrammer 11g standard edition

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42119/passing-parameters-to-a-procedure-executed-by-dbms-scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You can also invoke a procedure without using a program. Please take a look at this. (Also, auto_drop is true by default)

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(
   job_name        => 'JOB_Cleanse_BRNGB'
  ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
  ,job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
  ,start_date      =>  SYSDATE
  ,job_style       => 'LIGHTWEIGHT'
  ,job_action      => 'OPT_SALES'
  ,number_of_arguments   =>  1
);

dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(
                           job_name=>'JOB_Cleanse_BRNGB',
                           argument_name=>'CARD_NO',---> error says here
                           argument_value=>'1234');
dbms_scheduler.enable('JOB_Cleanse_BRNGB');
```